# Load Data while Scrolling Page Down with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

What is the right way to load data (json) with `angular` when scrolling down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did is make a directive that binds to the scroll event of the window and calls a scope function to load the data.

Or you could use [ngInfiniteScroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll).

Comment: Provided link is dead

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="i in items">{{product.name}}</li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
var counter = 0;
$scope.products = [];
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $scope.products.push({name: counter});
        counter += 10;
    }

};
 $scope.loadMore(); 
}]);

myApp.directive("whenScrolled", function(){
return{

restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

  // we get a list of elements of size 1 and need the first element
  raw = elem[0];

  // we load more elements when scrolled past a limit
  elem.bind("scroll", function(){
    if(raw.scrollTop+raw.offsetHeight+5 >= raw.scrollHeight){
      scope.loading = true;

    // we can give any function which loads more elements into the list
      scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrolled);
    }
   });
  }
 }
});
```

Working Example:http://plnkr.co/edit/FBaxdekW1Ya04S7jfz0V?p=preview?

Comment: upvoted because this is what I am looking for. P.S as a programmer i don't need detailed information, i just examine the code and I my self checked if this block is useful. thanks! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Scroll: Display only a small subset of the data that is in the viewport and keep changing the records as the user scrolls. It keeps the number of DOM elements constant hence boosting the performance of the application.

**this article so helpful**

https://medium.com/codetobe/learn-how-to-us-virtual-scrolling-in-angular-7-51158dcacbd4